# Strange behaviour with Html.EnableClientValidation in IE10

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I use HTML Helper to validate fields at client side. Although I do not put any Require validation on all fields, I still cannot submit the form because these fields are required as validation!? but if I close the form and re-open, the form can be submitted normally.

This problem just happens in IE10(not Firefox or Chrome).

Is there anyone stuck in this issue before?

Comment: check your html..I think there is some error in html

Comment: I did double check, I can ensure there is no error

Comment: may be "submit" button is overlapped with other div element?